# JDK 6 and linux

Tags: applet, java

I have just watched the bug report https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6972329 so I want  to ask... Is there a JDK upgraded version which handles the problem? Because if I develop an app with 32-bit JDK 6 will it work on 64-bit linux?
I have compiled my project with jdk 1.6.0_05 so I am not sure will it work for 32 or 64 bit linux ... won't it be the user.home as '?'

Thanks

Comment: The bug description (especially the evaluation) makes it look like a 32bit library (the one handling ldap interaction in PAM) is missing, so effectively it's a mis-configured system and not a bug in the JDK. Unfortunately the file with the most information (`strace.txt`) is not attached to the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug has absolutely nothing to do with the JDK used to compile Java code - Java bytecode is completely platform independant. The bug only occurs when you run a Java app on a 32bit JVM on a 64bit Linux, and even then it seems to depend on a specific (and possibly faulty) LDAP configuration.

Comment: You mean that linux must have correct JRE installed to avoid the bug? And please decrypt what the "a specific (and possibly faulty) LDAP configuration" is?

Comment: @user592704: well, running a 32bit JVM on a 64bit OS is not *incorrect*, but if you use a 64bit JVM, the bug apparently will not occur. As for the LDAP part, read the "Evaluation" section of the bug report.

Comment: so it is a platform depandant bug... so as a rule, linux 64 bit OS must have installed its right JRE ? I face the thing first. For some reason I guessing why my applet cannot get the "user.home" on linux OS but on Windows OS... So I think this is the answer :)

Comment: what system parameter shows the current OS bit? Is it the "sun.arch.data.model"?